# How do the code make to do something if code doesn't get the expected TYPE in python

Tags: python

In this custom-made function, I try to calculate the area of a circle. So if the user inputs not an integer as the **Count of circles** I want to go back again to **Count of Circle** and I can't figure out how I should do it. *Same goes for* ***Value of angle***.

```
def circlearea (r):
    print ("Calculating Area Of A Circle")
    radius = r
    print ("Radius Is ", radius)
    pi = 22/7

    # Count Of Circles Section 
    circleLoop = 1
    while circleLoop == 1:
    
        circles = input("Count Of Circle: ")

        if type(circles) is not int:
            circles = int(circles)
            circleLoop = 2
        else :
            print (323)
            circleLoop = 1
            

    # Value Of Angle Section 
    angleLoop = 1
    while angleLoop == 1:
        
        angle = input("The Value Of Angle: ")
    
        if angle is int or float:
            angle = float(angle)
            break
        else :
            print (False)
            print ("Invalid Angle Please Try Again !!")
        
    area = pi*radius**2*(angle/360)*circles
    print ("Area Of This Circle Is: ", area)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle this case using try except. Try like this

```
# Count Of Circles Section 
circleLoop = 1
while circleLoop == 1:

    circles = input("Count Of Circle: ")
    try:
        circles = int(circles)
    except:
        print("invalid")
        continue # if its not integer it will continue to loop again

    if type(circles) is not int:
        circles = int(circles)
        circleLoop = 2
    else:
        print(323)
        circleLoop = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Exception Handling to solve this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).